# What can I say for this function sequence $n-n^2x$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

I know it is easy but I am unable to see this function sequence’s limit. 
$f_n(x)=n-n^2x$ what can I say for limit of this sequence when $x$ in $(0,1/n)$ interval?

Comment: Its limit in infinity function because $n^2$ grows faster than $n$!

Comment: @GhD is it divergent sequence?

Comment: $n^2x$ where $x$ is in the interval, $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ is the same as $nx$ where $x$ is in the interval, $(0,1)$. So when $x$ is $0$, the sequence is just $n$, tending to infinity. When $x$ is $1$, (equivalently $\frac{1}{n}$), the limit is $0$.

Comment: yes, it is divergent sequence of functions.

Comment: @stuartstevenson therefore is it divergent?

Comment: @GhD thank you sir :)

Comment: Yes, when $x$ is not $\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: @stuartstevenson thanks sir

Comment: @GhD Notation: At first I thought you were saying that $n^2$ grows faster than $n$ factorial. Exclamation points can be dangerous...